# Coursera ML - Implementing regularized logistic regression cost function in python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I am working through Andrew Ng's Machine Learning on Coursera by implementing all the code in python rather than MATLAB.

In Programming Exercise 3, I implemented my regularized logistic regression cost function in a vectorized form:

```
def compute_cost_regularized(theta, X, y, lda):
    reg =lda/(2*len(y)) * np.sum(theta**2) 
    return 1/len(y) * np.sum(-y @ np.log(sigmoid(X@theta)) 
                         - (1-y) @ np.log(1-sigmoid(X@theta))) + reg
```

On the following test inputs:

```
theta_test = np.array([-2,-1,1,2])
X_test = np.concatenate((np.ones((5,1)), 
         np.fromiter((x/10 for x in range(1,16)), float).reshape((3,5)).T), axis = 1)
y_test = np.array([1,0,1,0,1])
lambda_test = 3
```

the above cost function outputs `3.734819396109744`. However, according to the skeleton MATLAB code provided to us, the correct output should be `2.534819`. I'm puzzled because I cannot find anything wrong with my cost function but I believe it has a bug. In fact, I've also [implemented it](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/kohaugustine/Machine-Learning-Coursera/blob/master/machine-learning-ex2/Programming%20Exercise%202%20-%20Logistic%20Regression.ipynb#Regularized-Cost-and-Gradient-Functions) in Programming Exercise 2 in the binary classification case and it works fine, giving a [result close to the expected value](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/kohaugustine/Machine-Learning-Coursera/blob/master/machine-learning-ex2/Programming%20Exercise%202%20-%20Logistic%20Regression.ipynb#Checking-the-accuracy).

I thought that one reason could be that I've constructed my `*_test` input arrays wrongly based on misinterpreting the provided skeleton MATLAB code which are:

```
theta_t = [-2; -1; 1; 2];
X_t = [ones(5,1) reshape(1:15,5,3)/10];
y_t = ([1;0;1;0;1] >= 0.5);
lambda_t = 3;
```

However, I had ran them through an Octave interpreter to see what they actually are, and ensure that I could match them exactly in python.

Furthermore, the computation of gradient based on these inputs using my own vectorized and regularized gradient function is also correct. Lastly, I decided to just proceed with the computation and examine the prediction results. The accuracy of my predictions were way lower than the expected accuracy, so it gives all the more reason to suspect that something is wrong with my cost function that is making everything else wrong.

Help please! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you recall from regularization, you do **not** regularize the bias coefficient.  Not only do you set the gradient to zero when performing gradient descent but you do not include this in the cost function.  You have a slight mistake where you are including this as part of the sum (see cell #18 on your notebook that you linked - the sum should start from `j = 1` but you have it as `j = 0`).  Therefore, you need to sum from the second element to the end for your `theta`, not the first.  You can verify this on Page 9 of the `ex2.pdf` PDF assignment that is seen on your Github repo.  This explains the inflated cost as you are including the bias unit as part of the regularization.

Therefore, when computing regularization in `reg`, index `theta` so that you start from the second element and onwards:

```
def compute_cost_regularized(theta, X, y, lda):
    reg =lda/(2*len(y)) * np.sum(theta[1:]**2) # Change here
    return 1/len(y) * np.sum(-y @ np.log(sigmoid(X@theta)) 
                         - (1-y) @ np.log(1-sigmoid(X@theta))) + reg
```

Once I do this, define your test values as well as define your `sigmoid` function, I get the right answer that you're expecting:

```
In [8]: def compute_cost_regularized(theta, X, y, lda):
   ...:     reg =lda/(2*len(y)) * np.sum(theta[1:]**2)
   ...:     return 1/len(y) * np.sum(-y @ np.log(sigmoid(X@theta))
   ...:                          - (1-y) @ np.log(1-sigmoid(X@theta))) + reg
   ...:

In [9]: def sigmoid(z):
   ...:     return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-z))
   ...:

In [10]: theta_test = np.array([-2,-1,1,2])
    ...: X_test = np.concatenate((np.ones((5,1)),
    ...:          np.fromiter((x/10 for x in range(1,16)), float).reshape((3,5)).T), axis = 1)
    ...: y_test = np.array([1,0,1,0,1])
    ...: lambda_test = 3
    ...:

In [11]: compute_cost_regularized(theta_test, X_test, y_test, lambda_test)
Out[11]: 2.5348193961097438
```

Comment: Thank you for finding my mistake! This does fix the function! I have also now applied the change to my notebook for programming exercise 2 and push to my Github. I wonder why this did not affect my model's performance in the exercise though...

Comment: Sorry @rayryeng, I'm still not sure why `scipy.optimize.minimize` would not require the cost function beyond the first call to it, if I understand your answer correctly. In the printed output from the optimization as you can see on my notebook,  `Iterations: 19` and `Function evaluations: 55`, where `Function` refers to the cost function (which was initially coded wrongly) that I provided to `minimize()`. Does it not use the cost function multiple times during optimization?

Comment: @AKKA You are correct. I apologize.  I'll delete the previous comment.  You require the cost function and optionally the gradient can be used for exact gradients rather than using numerical approximations.  However, because you specified the correct gradient initially, it no longer uses the cost function to guide in the direction of where the minimum occurs and the cost function is only used to evaluate what the cost of the parameters are at each step.  Therefore, the cost function output reported is not correct, but the correct gradient is being used to go to the minimum (continuing below).

Comment: Even though the cost function has changed, it is **only** being used to evaluate the cost of the parameters at each step.  It is **not** being used to steer the parameters in the direction of the minimum.  You will notice a difference if you **do not** specify the gradient as a parameter and allow the gradient to be computed by numerical approximations.  When you do this and you specify the buggy cost function and the correct one, the buggy one will report the incorrect minimum and the correct one should be similar to before. FYI, it will take longer as you don't have the exact gradient.

Comment: I understand it now. I also tried what you suggested, to call `minimize` without providing the gradient and using the incorrect regularized cost function, and I started getting poorer results. The running time also becomes much longer indeed. Thank you!

Comment: My pleasure. Keep asking questions if you need any more help. Good luck!

Comment: Hi rayryeng: Sorry that I'm hijacking my own question to bring to your attention a new question, related to the same exercise. I would really appreciate any help on it. Thank you very much! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44915145/coursera-ml-does-the-choice-of-optimization-algorithm-affect-the-accuracy-of-m