# Coursera ML - Does the choice of optimization algorithm affect the accuracy of multiclass logistic regression?

Tags: python, optimization, machine-learning, scipy, logistic-regression

I recently completed [exercise 3 of Andrew Ng's Machine Learning on Coursera using Python](https://github.com/kohaugustine/Machine-Learning-Coursera/blob/master/machine-learning-ex3/Programming%20Exercise%203%20-%20Multi-class%20Classification%20and%20Neural%20Networks.ipynb).

When initially completing parts 1.4 to 1.4.1 of the exercise, I ran into difficulties ensuring that my trained model has the accuracy that matches the expected 94.9%. Even after debugging and ensuring that my cost and gradient functions were bug free, and that my predictor code was working correctly, I was still getting only 90.3% accuracy. I was using the conjugate gradient (CG) algorithm in scipy.optimize.minimize.

Out of curiosity, I decided to try another algorithm, and used Broyden–Fletcher–Goldfarb–Shannon (BFGS). To my surprise, the accuracy improved drastically to 96.5% and thus exceeded the expectation. The comparison of these two different results between CG and BFGS can be viewed in my [notebook](https://github.com/kohaugustine/Machine-Learning-Coursera/blob/master/machine-learning-ex3/Programming%20Exercise%203%20-%20Multi-class%20Classification%20and%20Neural%20Networks.ipynb) under the header Difference in accuracy due to different optimization algorithms.

Is the reason for this difference in accuracy due to the different choice of optimization algorithm? If yes, then could someone explain why?

Also, I would greatly appreciate any review of my code just to make sure that there isn't a bug in any of my functions that is causing this. I suspect also that there could be bug which is responsible for this.

Thank you.

**EDIT:** Here below I added the code involved in the question, to make it easier for anyone to help me without referring to my Jupyter notebook.

Model cost functions:

```
def sigmoid(z):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-z))

def compute_cost_regularized(theta, X, y, lda):
    reg =lda/(2*len(y)) * np.sum(theta[1:]**2) 
    return 1/len(y) * np.sum(-y @ np.log(sigmoid(X@theta)) 
                             - (1-y) @ np.log(1-sigmoid(X@theta))) + reg

def compute_gradient_regularized(theta, X, y, lda):
    gradient = np.zeros(len(theta))
    XT = X.T
    beta = sigmoid(X@theta) - y
    regterm = lda/len(y) * theta
    # theta_0 does not get regularized, so a 0 is substituted in its place
    regterm[0] = 0 
    gradient = (1/len(y) * XT@beta).T + regterm
    return gradient
```

Function that implements one-vs-all classification training:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def train_one_vs_all(X, y, opt_method):
    theta_all = np.zeros((y.max()-y.min()+1, X.shape[1]))
    for k in range(y.min(),y.max()+1):
        grdtruth = np.where(y==k, 1,0)
        results = minimize(compute_cost_regularized, theta_all[k-1,:], 
                           args = (X,grdtruth,0.1),
                           method = opt_method, 
                           jac = compute_gradient_regularized)
        # optimized parameters are accessible through the x attribute
        theta_optimized = results.x
        # Assign thetheta_optimized vector to the appropriate row in the 
        # theta_all matrix
        theta_all[k-1,:] = theta_optimized
    return theta_all
```

Called the function to train the model with different optimization methods:

```
theta_all_optimized_cg = train_one_vs_all(X_bias, y, 'CG')  # Optimization performed using Conjugate Gradient
theta_all_optimized_bfgs = train_one_vs_all(X_bias, y, 'BFGS') # optimization performed using Broyden–Fletcher–Goldfarb–Shanno
```

We see that prediction results differ based on the algorithm used:

```
def predict_one_vs_all(X, theta):
    return np.mean(np.argmax(sigmoid(X@theta.T), axis=1)+1 == y)*100

In[16]: predict_one_vs_all(X_bias, theta_all_optimized_cg)
Out[16]: 90.319999999999993

In[17]: predict_one_vs_all(X_bias, theta_all_optimized_bfgs)
Out[17]: 96.480000000000004
```

For anyone wanting to get any data to try the code, they can find it in my Github as linked in this post.

Comment: I once discovered a bug that was spiking the accuracy of my MNIST digit recognition neural network by 15%.

Comment: What was that bug? I'm wondering if that could be anything related to something in my implementation...

Comment: Ah, it had to do with the way I was carrying out back propagation in the convolution layer. I wasn't rotating the filters.

Comment: I see. I'll be implementing a neural network in the next exercise 4, but a simple one that does not use convolutions.

Comment: Would I be troubling you too much now to ask if you could take a look at my code in my notebook please?

Comment: I took a look. Everything seems fine at first glance. Nice job :)

Comment: that makes this discrepancy all the more puzzling :S

Comment: thank you nonetheless :)

Comment: Each algorithm more or less gets you to the same minimum.  What is different is how much of a push towards the minimum each algorithm performs.  BFGS gets you towards the minima by approximating the Hessian matrix, which is known to get you towards the minimum much more faster than gradient-based approaches.  Try increasing the maximum number of iterations for the CG algorithm and try decreasing the tolerance that the norm of the gradient needs to be for convergence (i.e. the `gtol` parameter) and see if that helps in accuracy. This is a comment as I'm not sure if this will solve your problem.

Comment: @rayryeng: Thank you for the kind suggestion, but unfortunately this did not solve the issue. I tried adding in the additional parameter `options = {"maxiter":100000, "gtol": 1e-09}` into the call to `minimize()` but the results are still exactly the same, with CG giving 90.3% and BFGS giving 96%. I understand what you mean. The minimum is defined by the regularized cost function so it is the same cost to minimize regardless of whatever algorithm is used. Could it be that I'm stuck in a local minimum? But the cost function given to us should be convex....so I'm really puzzled...

Comment: Separately, I created a similar thread on Data Science Stackexchange, which has led to a pretty productive discussion for anyone who is interested in following this matter: 
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/20170/coursera-ml-does-the-choice-of-optimization-algorithm-affect-the-accuracy-of-m